Do parts sold with a core charge mean anything about the part's history?
Does a core fee imply anything specific about the part you purchase like it being used or rebuilt or in some way not fully new, maybe refurbished or something along those lines. I'm trying to learn if there's an association with that fee where you could question the mechanical fitness or safeness of the unit in anyway. A related question would be are there ever any new parts sold with core charges? Some parts have core charges associated with them while others do not, what exactly determines when you get charged a core charge fee and does it have any implication for the part you receive?

A core charge implies a value to the returned item. As an example, brake shoes "from the old days" required a metal structure on which to bond the friction material. Unless the friction material was worn beyond limits, there would be no damage to the metal structure. This would be cleaned and new friction material bonded, ready to be sold.
One could receive replacement brake shoes constructed from returned core items and have no concerns about safety, as the returned items would have been inspected for suitability.
Other items involved in core charges may have recycle value rather than refurbishment value. An example is a flooded lead acid battery. In a manner of speaking, it may be "refurbished," but mostly by disposing of the case and other useless components and recycling the lead.
More complex items can also be considered for this business model, but a specific part escapes my alleged mind.

A starter is a good example: much of the material value of a starter doesn't wear out, so a starter returned to the rebuilder can be cleaned up and have any worn or burned out parts replaced at comparatively lower cost than making everything new. A rebuilt starter that I'm on now has lasted longer than the factory new Bosch starter.
